# Parsing pseudo code/language in Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

So I need to write a parser (or simulator) which would take an input file with simple code written in my own pseudo code like language, for instance:

```
a = 5
b = 5 * a
[FOR 10]
    b = b * 5
[ENDFOR]
[IF b>30]
    a = a + 3
[ENDIF]
```

So the pseudo language only supports **integer** variables, basic operations with them (+,-,/,*), a basic for loop and a basic if statement. I need to build parser that will in the end deliver the final values of a and b (or any other variables used in the code).

I was thinking of trying to do this in XML so I simulate the loop and the if with tags, but I am not really sure if this is the right (or most efficient) approach. Any suggestions?

Quick edit ^^:
It's not about my own programming language...it's part of a bigger project...I need a simple way of evaluating small snippets of code written like the example and get the states of the variables used after simulating it...thats why I wanted to use XML...this is not intended to be a programming lanuage of any sort...

Comment: If there's an implementation, it's not pseudo code. You want to build your own little programming language, which is a good thing :) But you'll need to spell out all the details to implement them, and you'll need to use a full parsing library. And please don't abuse XML as programming language... that way lies madness.

Comment: Yeah it's not really about my own programming language...it's part of a bigger project...I need a simple way of evaluating small snippets of code written like the example and get the states of the variables used after simulating it...thats why I wanted to use XML...this is not intended to be a programming lanuage of any sort...

Comment: It has variables, math, conditionals, loops... sounds pretty much like a programming language. A very simple one, granted, but still a programming language. Anyway: Where does this "pseudo"code come from in the first place?

Comment: Amen, @delnan - please use XML for configuration or data, but not for procedural code.

Comment: Yeah it does...but still I only need a way to get the final variable state...the pseudo code will be written by me...a few short and easy algorithms...all only using the things mentioned above...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much of this may already be implemented using the examples from the pyparsing wiki, such as [this one](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/SimpleCalc.py), or [this one](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/eval_arith.py), which uses the more current `operatorPrecedence` helper method.

**EDIT** Links to PyParsing Wikispace are dead but you can found an another wiki on the github repository from here : https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing/wiki

Comment: This is probaly the most elegant solution...I will look into it...THX

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [PLY](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/). Python's implementation of glorious LEX/YACC. You can **definitely** write a compiler or interpreter for your language with this tool.